# Как автоматически проставить пакеты в классах в Intelli IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Добрый день!

Залил себе чужой проект и столкнулся с проблемой, что в классах не прописаны пакеты в которых они находятся. Есть ли в Intellij IDEA какой нибудь инструмент чтобы автоматически проставить пакеты, а то классов десятки и в ручную их ставить не вариант. Вроде как, когда создаешь файл, то IDEA автоматически прописывает пакет сверху класса.

Comment: Все классы без пакетов подсвечиваются инспектором. Попробовал выбрать класс и нажать "Alt" + "Enter", инспектор предложил добавить пакет, я нажал "Enter" и пакет добавился. Определенно легче, чем самому прописывать, но всё равно классов много. Есть ли возможность сразу добавить пакеты для все классов?

Comment: так как в вопросе речь идет все таки об автоматическом проставлении пакетов,а не классав, вдобавок вам ответ не помог, я удалю ответ и создам новый вопрос/ответ конкретно по импорту классов.